Show footer only on the last page of the BIRT report
In my report, there is a header which needs to be displayed on all the pages. After the header, there will be a grid with multiple rows. Each row of the grid can be of variable length (because of description field) and it can occupy more space based on the size of the description.
If the grid has more rows then it will overflow to the next pages and on the last page I need to display the footer.
I tried using 2 master pages as mentioned in the answer here How to display footer only on first page (birt conditional display footer)
However, I don't know when to do the page break since the number of rows in the grid can vary based on size of description field.
Any help is much appreciated.

The title and the text contradict:
Title: "first page", text: "last page".
If you want to show the footer only on the first page:
The concept of using 2 master pages to solve this only works if your grid (or table or whatever) should start after the first page, or if you know a specific grid row which should start on page 2.
However, this doesn't apply to your use-case.
An alternative approach would be using separate RunTask and RenderTask, and page variables (I never tested this myself). For example, you could use a page variable to store the number of the first (=minimum) grid row of your page and reset it for each page.
Then, in the master page, you can use this page variable as a visibility expression for your footer.
However, the place will still be reserved for the footer on the following pages.
If you want to show the footer only on the bottom of the last page, you could use a similar approach.
The way I would do it in our reports (for showing the footer on the bottom of the last page) is yet another:
I'd add a fixed height empty row as the last line of the grid, just to reserve space. Then I'd use a PDF post-processor outside of BIRT to add the footer on the last page. The BIRT reports writes text and formatting instructions for the post-processor into the appContext, the post-processor reads these data and uses OpenPDF to render it. But this approach requires that BIRT is integrated into your application.
I don't think that there is a straightforward way to get what you want.
